# Alphanumeric regex expression in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c, regex

I am new in the programming and i am looking for a regular expression as

first three characters should be alphanumeric followed by a constant which is a special character and then 1 or more hashes

(3 alphanumeric) (constant) ( one or more hashes)

AB1-#
ABC$##
etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like

```
(\w{3})([^\s])(#+)
```